# How and why do electric fields occur when we put a voltage difference between two point?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

When we put a voltage differences between two points on a certain sample, I would like to know how and why the electric field occurs. In addition, I would like to know in what shape does the electric field occur. Does it have the same shape of the electric field which occurs between two point charges + and -?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Why?" questions are always a bit dubious in physics, but let me explain a few words here:

"Voltage" is in itself a difference, and it is (by definition) the difference of electric potential energy. The difference in electric potential energy is by definition the work needed to move a test charge against the electric field. In other words: The electric field is the fundamental thing here, not "Voltage".

Therefore, let's consider the question the other way round: **What leads to a difference in potential energy?**

Suppose you have an electrically charged object. Suppose you have another charged object, then you can measure a force exerted by the first object on the second. If you move the second object around, you get a force (direction and quantity) at every point in space. Let's call this the "electric field". Instead of any object, let's assume that the object is a pointlike particle, i.e. we take a charged object so very small that we can hardly see it. Then these objects/particles have an electric field which is given by [Coulomb's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb's_law): A unit charged (i.e. another charged particle with charge $1$) at distance $r$ from the particle will experience the force

$$F(r)=k\frac{q}{r} $$

where $k$ is some constant and $q$ is the charge of the particle. This is the definition of an electric field of a particle and also gives you its "shape". Now by a [curious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) fact of nature, the electric field is additive, which means that if you have more particles, the shape of the field changes by just adding the different forces from each particle at each point. This tells you that the electric field can come in very different shapes, always depending on the distribution of charges. As an example, have a look at the field of four particles [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/VFPt_four_charges.svg/2000px-VFPt_four_charges.svg.png).

Now what about the "voltage"? By another curious fact of nature, if I move a particle from point $A$ to point $B$ in a static electric field, it doesn't matter which way I choose, the work is independent of the way. This is why it makes sense to speak of the work difference between points $A$ and $B$ - which defines "electrostatic potential energy difference" or else voltage.